# Run docker-compose on Windows 7

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using Docker Toolbox to run docker containers on Windows. When I try to perform `docker-compose up` Docker cannot find `docker-compose.yml`. I must `cd` into container's directory or specify the file path using -f argument. How to get the path?

`docker info` shows Root Dir as `/mtn/sda1/bla/bla` which is virtual path and doesn't exist on my PC.

UPD: solved

Answer (score 1):

You may have simply forgot to save the docker-compose.yml. check this first. Try this solution, it worked for me https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/129

hope you get it sorted

Comment: No, I was thinking that I should pull docker image from Docker Hub than call docker-compose :) That was stupid assumption. I just need to place Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml somewhere on my PC, cd there and call docker-compose up. That's it!